# How to make 301 redirect in Jetty

Tags: http, jetty

How to realize 301 redirect from http to https in Jetty? I know that in Jetty MovedContextHandler work with redirects but don't know how to set parameters.

Comment: Are you wanting to redirect within your own webapp? your own context? or before it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the version 9.0.6 of Jetty, here's the basic (and quite clear) description of how to do the redirect: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.0.6.v20130930/moved-context-handler.html.